# PHP+MSSQL JOIN two tables outputs nothing - "No tuples"

Tags: php, sql-server, join, tuples

```
$conn=odbc_connect('mydatabase','','');
$sql="SELECT 
    Orders.OrderID,
    Orders.OrderDate,
    \"Order Details\".OrderID,
    \"Order Details\".UnitPrice,
    \"Order Details\".Quantity,
    \"Order Details\".Discount,
  FROM 
    \"Order Details\"
  INNER JOIN 
    Orders 
  ON \"Order Details\".OrderID = Orders.OrderID";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql) or die("<p>".odbc_errormsg());
while (($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) !== false)
```

When I try to output the results of $rs nothing is returned. If I try to access fields from either Orders or \"Order Details\" separately it works fine but if I try to JOIN the two tables it outputs nothing.

Is this the correct way to SELECT a field from a table that has a space in its name when using MSSQL? It seems to work when I try "SELECT * FROM \"Order Details\"" but when I try to join the tables I have to specify "\Order Details\".OrderID and I think that might be where it's getting confused.

Apache error log returns a strange "odbc_fetch_array(): No tuples available at this result" message, but I'm not positive this is the actual problem as I've seen this error message pop up randomly for unrelated reasons. Still, I don't quite understand it so thought I should mention it.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you put the query straight into the database?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "/", use brackets.

```
"SELECT Orders.OrderID, [Order Details].UnitPrice 
 FROM [Order Details] INNER JOIN Orders ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've tried square brackets and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Are Orders.OrderID and [Order Details].OrderID of the same datatype?

Comment: One is a number and another is an autonumber according to Access. Would that be causing the problem? I'm new to php and had assumed that it would still treat them as the same.

Comment: Assuming that both are integers, it shouldn't be a problem.  Can you add some data from both tables to your question.  This might help.